# comparable, comparator return negative,positive, zero in java

Tags: java, collections

I need to know how the `compareTo(...)` method works internally. Based on the result will it swap the values?

```
Condition:

1. If obj1 is less than object2 will return negative.
2. If obj1 is greater than object2 will return positive.
3. If obj1 is equal to object2 will return zero.
```

How the `compareTo(...)` method works internally based on the conditions

```
@Override
public int compareTo(DVDInfo o) {       
    return title.compareTo(o.title); // for title sort      
}
```

Comment: What you mean "swap the values"?

Comment: Yes. You'r right. What is your question?

Comment: You are asking how compareTo method in String.java works?

Comment: Ingo: say I added multiple DVDInfo to an ArrayList<DVDInfo> arrayList = new ArrayList<DVDInfo>();and I used Collections.sort(arrayList). when I iterate the arrayList the title gets sorted.so how the compareTo Method works internally

Comment: Submin: my question is how compareTo method works for custom object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no, something ELSE swaps the values!  For example, when you call `Arrays.sort`, the code inside `Arrays.sort` does all the swapping around that is required by whatever sort algorithm it uses.  The `compareTo` method just tells it how to decide whether it NEEDS to swap things.  Based on whether `compareTo` returns negative, zero, or positive; the `sort` method works out how to reorder the elements of the array.  To do this, of course, it will end up calling `compareTo` many times.

Answer (score 1):

The `compareTo` method compares two objects with each other, and returns a value indicating the order of the two objects.

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "bcd";
s1.compareTo(s2); // returns negative value
s2.compareTo(s1); // returns positive value
```

There is no swapping of objects or anything like that, the value returned is only an indication of the order of the elements. On strings this order is alphabetical (i.e. "abc" is before "bcd" alphabetically).

If you need to sort a collection of strings, use `Collections.sort()`. This method will use the string `compareTo` method to determine the order of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) for `String.compareTo()`. If you have other Locale than English, you should better use `java.text.Collator` for string comparsion.